# Properties window, Basic Tab Pie Chart

Tags: disk-usage, file-properties

I am wondering about the pie chart in the properties basic tab. I can see blue is used space and white free space but what does the gray part mean. I have been searching with no luck. Thanks in advanced!

[image: Properties Window]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the file system reserves 5% for the root user, which is what you're seeing in gray. You can change this using `tune2fs`. For example, to change the reserved space to 1% you would use:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdb1
```

where `/dev/sdb1` is the location of your drive.

I have tested this successfully on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Right, that was it, thanks! Anyway I was worried to reduce the reserved space as you suggested but after some digging I found it is fairly safe to do it since it is not the system drive. And while Ext3 is prone to fragmentation and bad performance above 95% usage, Ext4's multi-block allocator is much more fragmentation resistant, as mentioned by Linux filesystem developer and guru [Theodore Ts'o](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Ts%27o): **[Re: Reserved block count for Large Filesystem](https://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2009-January/msg00026.html)**